# What file-format is this?

Tags: file-format

I've been using this file-format below as an alternative for flat-text files, and I'm wondering if there is a name for it...

Say you have this data in a CSV:

```
FirstName,LastName,Email,UserName,Notes
Bob,Smith,bsmith@email.com,bsmith,Bob likes chicken
John,Doe,jdoe@email.com,jdoe,
Steve,Jobs,STEVE@apple.com,STEVE,Steve Jobs likes things that start with "i"
```

In this "other" file format, there are 3 columns:

1. Unique ID
2. Attribute Name
3. Value

The above data would look like this:

```
bmsith@email.com,FirstName,Bob
bmsith@email.com,LastName,Smith
bmsith@email.com,Email,bmsith@email.com
bmsith@email.com,UserName,bsmith
bmsith@email.com,Notes,Bob likes chicken
jdoe@email.com,FirstNameJohn
jdoe@email.com,LastName,Doe
jdoe@email.com,Email,jdoe@email.com
jdoe@email.com,UserName,jdoe
STEVE@apple.com,FirstName,Steve
STEVE@apple.com,LastName,Jobs
STEVE@apple.com,Email,STEVE@apple.com
STEVE@apple.com,UserName,STEVE
STEVE@apple.com,Notes,Steve Jobs likes things that start with "i"
```

I actually delimit on tab, but comma is easier to read for this. And in this example, any of the attributes could be used as a unique identifier.

Comment: Question isn't particularly clear- could you elaborate?

Comment: Is this a format you created or something being required by another system?

Comment: Why would you use this format? It seems terribly inefficient. What's the benefit?

Comment: Don't take this personally but the more I look at the second example you give the more brain dead it is.

Comment: I updated the example to be more complete... the benefit it you don't need to have all of the attributes in a header row (so you could have thousands of attribute names with still having 3 columns...), and you don't end up with NULLs if a row doesn't have a specific attribute... you just omit that line

Comment: Having all the attributes named _once_ in a header row is way better than having them repeated once _for every entity_. Not to mention having the ID field repeated once for every attribute. If you want to omit a particular attribute, what's wrong with just leaving that field blank?

Comment: @jcoon - still braindead. What if STEVE changes his email address? You're going up update every single row?

Comment: what happens when the data has a , in it?

Comment: also order does not matter... you can create these files incrementally.  It can be used to gather/extract content, and the be put into a database or XML later on (without duplicates and with less redundancy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took some time, but I found it.. it's [Entity Attribute Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) (EAV).

Answer (score 5):

It's still CSV.  You're just presenting the data from a different aspect, in terms of its structure, not its content.

Comment: Understandable... I'm wondering if there is a name though. It is CSV (or tab delimited), but it's not "flat-text"... is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you delimit on tab then it's a tab-delimited file. But I don't think there is a proprietary name for the particular format you show.

Answer (score 0):

I never saw this kind of data description before. But since it's in a coma separated format, I suppose it's still called CSV:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

But I think this way of saving this way uses a lot of unnecessary bytes since you repeat the uniqueID a lot and the attribute names too. The only advantage I can see is that the data can be randomly placed in a file. Other than that, text files are usually read sequentially.

--- Edit ---

From the wiki, there is a list of [human readable formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats#Syntax_comparison_of_human-readable_formats). If none of them suits you and still want to use your format and use a name, you could always use a more generic name like [Delimiter separated value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values) instead of CSV or invent a new one like key-field-value (KFV).

Answer (score 0):

The structure is called Key-Value table. And you have serialized that table as a CSV file.